# How can i get the value of the next row of my DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, compare, row, datagridviewrow

How can i get the value of the next row of my DataGridView in my FOREACH

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewSelection.Rows)
{
        if ((bool)((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[3]).Value)
        {
            do
            {
                list.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            } 
            while (row.Cells[2].Value == the next row.Cells[2].Value-->of the next row);

        }              
}
```

I want to obtain the value of the same cell in the next row so i can compare them.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a `for` loop instead of `foreach`, but this is simple since [DataGridViewRowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.aspx) implements the required info:

```
    for (int rowNum=0;rowNum<dataGridViewSelection.Rows.Count - 1; ++rowNum)
    {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridViewSelection.Rows[rowNum];
            if ((bool)((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells[3]).Value)                    {
                do
                {
                    list.Add(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                } while (row.Cells[2].Value == dataGridViewSelection.Rows[rowNum+1].Cells[2].Value);

            }              
    }
```

By indexing via the index, you can easily access any other row in your loop.